# Strange jump on map after click

Tags: angularjs, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, here-api

I have a strange problem with Here maps (JS).
After catching a click event on another element in the page (ex: custom bubble or search field) the map starts to flick like in the gif below

Example : https://i.imgur.com/kKrtwMj.gif

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution.

It consist of re-instantiate the H.mapevents.MapEvents object and the H.mapevents.Behavior at the time the bug occurs.

```
mapEvents.dispose();
mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);
behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents, { kinetics: { duration: 3, power: 1 } });
```